# Cocoa/Mac - external config settings for running app

Tags: cocoa, registry, application-settings

On windows, we use registry or .ini or xml config etc for settings that apps can pull in at run time w/o making code changes.

On Mac/Cocoa, what're the best approaches to do that and what are the corresponding APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i). NSUserDefaults stores the data as a property list in the ~/Library/Preferences directory.

Answer (score 1):

As @ughoavgfhw answered, per-user preferences should be stored in ~/Library/Preferences, and `NSUserDefaults` is available to support that.

If you are instead thinking of configuration information (the line between *configuration* and *preferences* being of course fuzzy) then you might wish to use the Application Support folder. There are two of these, per-user located at ~/Library/Application Support and system-wide at /Library/Application Support. In either of these create a folder named after your application or company and stored whatever you wish to in it. If you are planning on submitting to the Mac App Store only the per-user folder is allowed - you must replicate your configuration information for every user.